# Fastest way to iterate over array columns and stack them vertically

Tags: numpy, iteration

Some of this might not make much sense, but I just tried to simulate my problem as faithfully as possible. Despite this, the core of the problem is super simple, it's just an iteration where columns are grabbed sequentially and then stacked vertically, growing an array.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this? With my real data, this procedure takes almost 30 minutes. I'm downsizing the problem with the random data included in the snippet below.

```
import numpy as np
#Initialize big 3d arrays:
big_3d_arr_1=np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(20000, 15000,2))
big_3d_arr_2=np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(20000, 15000,2))


#Get slices and stack them:
slice_1 = np.vstack((big_3d_arr_1[:,-1,1],big_3d_arr_1[:,0,1],big_3d_arr_1[:,0,0] ) ).T
slice_2 = np.vstack((big_3d_arr_2[:,0,1],big_3d_arr_2[:,-1,1],big_3d_arr_2[:,0,0] ) ).T

slices = np.vstack(( slice_1,slice_2) )

#Iterate over rest of columns and grow a stacked array
for i in range(1, 1000):
    print(i)
    slice_1 = np.vstack((big_3d_arr_1[:,-1,1],big_3d_arr_1[:,i,1],big_3d_arr_1[:,0,0] ) ).T
    slice_2 = np.vstack((big_3d_arr_2[:,i,1],big_3d_arr_2[:,-1,1],big_3d_arr_2[:,0,0] ) ).T
    
    slices_0 = np.vstack(( slice_1,slice_2) )

    slices = np.vstack(( slices_0,slices) ) #new arrays go on top
```

Comment: Repeated `vstack` in a loop is slow.  Build a list (or lists), and do one (or few) `vstack`.  It's hard to tell, without a lot of tedious reading, what you are trying to, that is, to get the big picture.  Certainly with `randint` of that size, we can't compare the start arrays with the result.  With something small like `np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)` that's easier.  But I have a suspicion that you can do the job with some reshape and transpose (and more reshape).

Comment: Your code takes less than 1min30 on my machine, but it takes 10 GiB of memory! Are you sure you do not run out of memory (swapping)?